# How do I email MS Project calendar items to people with Thunderbird email clients?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-project

How do I send a .ICS or .VCS  vCard Outlook/Project calendar file items in a format that all email clients understand?   I don't want a .VCS attachment to show up in a Thunderbird Email client presented as text data.   Does the calendar item need to be pre-processed before sending in email?  How is this expected to work?

Comment: Please note that Thunderbird doesn't even come with a calendar module by default.

Comment: Yes, i know.  I dont want Thunderbird users to be able to integrate to a calender nor do i want them to open the attachment in a MS product.  I just want the Thunderbird receiver to be able to see a "normalized and nicely formatted" message that is at least half way legible.

Comment: Are you saying that Thunderbird garbles messages when an ICS or VCS is attached?